# find all partial limits of $x_n=\cos(\frac{9 \pi n}{2})$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to understand how to correctly find partial limits, I'm having really hard time doing so without drawing the cosinus function, what is the correct method to approach it?
I know it relates to $2\pi$ cycle but I seem to fail grasping the concept on how to find what values $\cos(\frac{9 \pi n}{2})$ takes.

A simplified example:
$x_n=\cos(\frac{9 \pi n}{2})$

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is meant by "partial limits"? Accumulation points?

Comment: Try plugging in values for $n$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos (2\pi + x) = \cos (x)$ so $\cos (9\pi n / 2) = \cos (n \pi / 2)$ and so you get $\cos(\pi / 2), \cos(\pi), \cos(3\pi/2), \cos(2 \pi)$ for $n = 1,2,3,4$ and then the values repeat in groups of 4 for higher $n$. So, depending on your definition for "partial limits,", can you see what the partial limits are?

Comment: Yes, Exactly the answer I was hoping for. By partial limits I think in English (Sorry, not my first language) the meaning is what are the partial series the $x_n$ series can output and what is the limit of each series if $n\rightarrow \infty$, so in my case it would be 1, 0 and -1.

Answer (score 1):

hint:

$$
\dfrac{9\pi n}{2} = \dfrac{8\pi n + \pi n}{2} = 2\pi n + \dfrac{\pi }{2}n
$$